# Tomcat virtual hosts accessible at two URLs

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost, tomcat6

I have some web apps deployed on Tomcat, using the following configuration:

```
<Engine ...>
    <Host name="a.mycompany.com" ...>
    <Host name="b.mycompany.com" ...>
    <Host name="c.mycompany.com" ...>
</Engine>
```

For each of these apps, I can access them at the following two URLs:

```
http://x.mycompany.com/
http://x.mycompany.com/x
```

Where `x` is `a`, `b` or `c`.

Is this normal, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the default configuration.

You have deployed all 3 web apps on a single Tomcat instance - so they will be accessible by default as

`http://<some-domain-url>/x` where `x = a,b` or `c`

Are you looking to restrict the pattern to

`http://a.mycompany.com/a` or `http://b.mycompany.com/b` and

**disallow** `http://a.mycompany.com/b` ?

Then try [nesting the web app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Nested_Components) via a `<Context>` element in the server.xml within your

```
<Host name="a.mycompany.com" ...>
```

Like so:

```
<Host name="a.mycompany.com" appBase="webapps"> 
    <Context path="/a" docBase="/a/"/> 
      </Host> 

      <Host name="b.mycompany.com" appBase="webapps"> 
    <Context path="/b" docBase="/b/"/> 
      </Host>
```

If `path` is set to `""` then you can get the app at the `ROOT` context, like `a.mycompany.com` instead of `a.mycompany.com/a`

Comment: What I want to achieve is http://a.mycompany.com/ being the only way accessing a - http://a.mycompany.com/a should give a 404

Comment: I dont think that is possible with Tomcat alone. You need an Apache to front it to redirect to a 404 error page on that URL pattern